# replace fragment happens just after program finish

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have main activity with list fragment on click item it replaces to a 'A fragment'.
In 'A fragment' there is start button, on click it, it has to be replaced with 'B fragment' and then exec functions
but it doesn't happen and on click start button, 'A fragment' got stuck till all the function of 'B fragment' is executed, and just then shows 'B fragment',
what can be the problem?

main activity function:

```
public void onTestStarted(Class testClass) {
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    mRunning = true;
    mTestFragment=TestFragment.newInstance(testClass);
    replaceFragment(mTestFragment);
    mThreadsManager = new ThreadsManager(testClass,mHandler);
        mThreadsManager.startTest();
}



public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment){
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

finally i succeed solved it by threading
(the thread handle the "B class" who exec the functions)
I set the thread process to be back-ground priority 
and it work....